# Multidimensional Array in vb net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I want to create 2 dimensional array(4,4).

```
1   5   9   13

2   6   10  14

3   7   11  15

4   8   12  16
```

However, when I created the code, it shows vertically, only 1 dimension.

```
1
2
3
4
.
.
```

This is my code

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    Dim array(3, 3) As Integer
    Dim array2 As Integer(,)
    array2 = New Integer(3, 3) {}

    array(0, 0) = "1"
    array(1, 0) = "2"
    array(2, 0) = "3"
    array(3, 0) = "4"
    array(0, 1) = "5"
    array(1, 1) = "6"
    array(2, 1) = "7"
    array(3, 1) = "8"
    array(0, 2) = "9"
    array(1, 2) = "10"
    array(2, 2) = "11"
    array(3, 2) = "12"
    array(0, 3) = "13"
    array(1, 3) = "14"
    array(2, 3) = "15"
    array(3, 3) = "16"

    lstArray.Items.Add(array(0, 0))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(1, 0))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(2, 0))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(3, 0))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(0, 1))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(1, 1))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(2, 1))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(3, 1))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(0, 2))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(1, 2))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(2, 2))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(3, 2))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(0, 3))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(1, 3))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(2, 3))
    lstArray.Items.Add(array(3, 3))

End Sub
End Class
```

How can I make this 2 dimensional array? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you debug the application and hover over lstArray, can you see what content is contained? Your code looks to be ok, but is incomplete. How are you iterating over lstArray (which I presume is a list of Int)?

Comment: Are you asking how to [make a listbox have multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15446674/11683)?

Comment: Your array is of type Integer, yet you are enclosing your values in double quotes.

Comment: Ok, for what you have shown, your code for creating the array (other than the double quotes) should work fine. Your use of the list object (lstArray) is I presume just so you can see the contents of the array. array2 doesn't need to be DIM'd if you're not using it, it just adds clutter. How are you displaying the content of the array?

Comment: I removed the double quotes. But it still doesn't work.  I display by using the button.

Comment: Your `array` is a two dimensional array, `lstArray` is clearly not a two dimensional array, it is presumably either a List(Of Integer), or a ListBox,

Answer (score 1):

You gave us the code for how you created the array, but not how you displayed it. I'm confident that your problem lies there (in the button_click event, or wherever your code reads the array back to you).

My guess is the unshared code has one of three problems:

1) It's only looping through 1 dimension of array. So where you have something like

```
For i = 0 To 3
    MsgBox(array(0, i)
Next
```

what you need is something like

```
For i = 0 To 3
    For j = 0 To 3
        MsgBox(array(i, j)
    Next
Next
```

2) It's referencing lstArray, but at some point confusing the structure of lstArray with that of array. Whereas array's indices range from (0,0) to (3,3), lstArray's range from (0) to (15). You could only be looping from 0 to 3 if you got your variables confused or changed from one to the other at some point in your coding.

3) There's a mistake somewhere in how you are concatenating (or otherwise combining) the separate items in lstArray into a single row.

See if you can solve or at least narrow down your problem based on these suggestions and then post the missing code if you still need help.

Comment: Thank you for the help. First, I will try by myself.